# Optimal algorithm to select unique values from a daily-growing list

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, optimization

Suppose I have a list of numbers, say $L$, that grows every day when a new batch of numbers get added to it every night. Right now, say the list is of size $M$, with the daily batch size is of the order $O(n)$ with $M>>n,$ so tomorrow the list will roughly have $M + O(n)$ numbers.

Based on this list $L$, I also maintain a daily-growing list $U$ that holds all the unique elements of $L.$ For example, if $L = [1,1,3,4,5,5]$, then $U = [1,3,4,5].$ Then, if today $L$ gets the new batch $[1,3,6,7]$, then tomorrow it will be $L = [1,1,1,3,3,4,5,5,6,7]$ and $U = [1,3,4,5,6,7].$

I want to optimize the computational complexity of computing $U$ from $L$ daily.  Of course the naive would be to do something like `Select distinct from L` (SQL) / `set(list(L))` (Python) daily to retrieve $U.$ But this re-calculates a lot of the calculations we did yesterday and I can't help but think this could be optimized more than the naive.

Very rough heuristics of the current naive approach as follows:

Suppose, I have to maintain this for $k$ consecutive days, starting with $M$ elements on the first day and adding $n$ every day. Being very rough here, let's assume the complexity of `set(list)` is $\alpha M$ for input of size $M$ with a constant $\alpha >0.$ Then, over the course of the $k$ days, I am looking at:
$$T = \alpha\sum_{i=1}^k(M+in) = \alpha kM + \alpha n\frac{k^2+k}{2}.$$

My question is can we do better than this ? Assume the sizes are roughly $M\sim 1000000, n\sim 5000$ and $k$ would just be $365$, or exactly a year, although these are very rough numbers and I would still be satisfied with a purely theoretical solution.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_algorithm, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(abstract_data_type), https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-balancing_binary_search_tree